# How to change from UEFI to legacy without reinstalling Windows?

Tags: windows-8, boot, usb, uefi

The machine has UEFI enabled. I can't boot anything except Windows; No bootable USBs. I have to change it to legacy mode, but Windows 8 won't boot in legacy mode. So the only solution I can think of is having to manually switch after every reboot.

Are there some sort of drivers I can install to Windows 8 to make it able to boot from legacy mode? Or do I have to reinstall?

Comment: Windows 8 can indeed boot but that requires you migrate from GPT to MBR.  If your disk is larger then MBR allows then your unlikely going to do that without significant amount of work.  How you covert to MBR without data loss is well documented

Comment: Of course you should be able to boot to EFI boot USB devices without an issue.  OEM are prohibited from blocking that ability

Comment: It has no fancy bootloaders installed, just the good old windows boot manager.  Also the hard drive is 500gb, so it is supported by mbr.